# Flagged Question as Spam, but Dialog Seems Confused

Tags: bug, flags, spam, offensive

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595279/blue-ray-watch-the-giver-online-full-movie-in-putlocker) as SPAM. For whatever reason, I clicked the link to flag it again, and when the dialog opened, it showed that I had flagged it as both SPAM *and* as offensive/abusive/hate speech (which I didn't). Why is it showing both flag reasons?

[image]

Comment: Agreed, the UI is confusing. I got tripped up by this myself recently: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6696/i-flagged-a-question-twice

Comment: Perhaps the devs could change the word "this" to "a mutually exclusive" on the not-raised flag?

Comment: They are the same *type* of flag, but not the same flag.

Answer (score 1):

Because to the system the flags are effectively the same. Both (if 6 users agree) carry a 100 point reputation penalty and both feed into the same moderator flag queue. Therefore, if you flag for spam you can't flag for offensive and vice versa. The only other way to do it would be to have a two step process:

> 1. Flag for spam or offensive
> 2. New dialog to say which one.

Which is one click too many.

If you could flag as both spam and offensive you could theoretically hit the user with a 200 point reputation penalty.

Also - something is either spam or offensive, I suppose it *could* be offensive spam, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: But my question is, why is the system showing me a dialog and effectively telling me that I clicked both flags when I didn't? Internally I don't care what's going on. The UI is misleading.

Comment: @j08691 The dialog says, "You have already raised this *type* of flag" (emphasis added). I can see how that could be confusing, but it certainly isn't saying you raised the *same* flag.